# TextArea AWT JAVA

Tags: java

I have the following task to do in Text Area AWT JAVA. I Have already a text in Text Area and now a need to replace this text by typing directly in Text Area a new text. This new text should cover existing text, so it is a kind an insert button. 
For example a have in my TextAarea "Home and Home"  I put the mouse before first Home and type "Gggg" so as a result I should have "Gggg and Home".

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for what? We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: I do not need the code. What i need is just a hint

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to enable the overwrite/insert mode on jtextarea.
This [link](http://java-sl.com/tip_overwrite_mode.html) shows some sample code which might be helpful.